# Saving a matrix in Matlab in a folder different from the working directory?

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to save a matrix in Matlab in a folder different from the working directory?
Suppose the current working directory is /Users/username/Desktop/Paper1 and the code is

```
clear all
load A
R=zeros(100,1)
for s=1:100
R(s)=randn(1)+A(s);
end

%save R in /Users/username/Desktop/Paper2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
This is a way. Type in the command window

```
cd /Users/username/Desktop/Paper2
```

than

```
save('file.mat','R')
```

If you want to go back to your previous current directory you can add to your code.

```
currentFolder = pwd
cd /Users/username/Desktop/Paper2
save('file.mat','R')
cd(currentFolder)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put the full path in the filename argument for `save`.

```
save('/path/to/desired/folder/filename.mat', R)
```

Comment: You should add the list of variables to be saved (in this case `'R'`) otherwise all warkspace variables will be saved in _filename.mat_.